# Module is not a loader must have normal or pitch function

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, umd

I am using a lib that is distributed as umd modules and the code from one of the file i am importing looks like this

lib.js

```
(function (global, factory) {
    if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define(['exports', '../utils/require-isdefined-plugin!lodash'], factory);
    } else if (typeof exports !== "undefined") {
        factory(exports, require('lodash'));
    } else {
        var mod = {
            exports: {}
        };
        factory(mod.exports, global.lodash);
        global.registry = mod.exports;
    }
})(this, function (exports, _lodash) {
    'use strict';
    // Library code
})
```

and now when i use this lib.js in my code and run webpack, it throws this error

**Error: Module 'H:\Projects\abc\umd\app\utils\require-isdefined-plugin.js' is not a loader (must have normal or pitch function)**

I think that webpack is treating "../utils/require-isdefined-plugin" as a loader and complaining.

My question is how can i let webpack know that this is not a loader and execute this file normally or

is there any other way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and frankly best solution would be to use a different build. Most libraries nowadays have a UMD build as well as an npm package.

If that is not an option you can use [`imports-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/imports-loader/) to disable the AMD `define` as shown in [Shimming - `imports-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/#imports-loader), so webpack doesn't touch it and will use the commonjs version. You would add a rule for the library:

```
{
  test: require.resolve('./path/to/lib'),
  loader: 'imports-loader?define=>false'
}
```

`require.resolve` works the same as the regular `require` but gives you the full path of the resolved module instead of its content, so you can still do `require.resolve('lib')` if that's how you imported it.

To be safe you should also exclude the library from your regular `.js` rule, because having two rules for the same file usually doesn't end well. Your rules might look like this:

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    exclude: [/node_modules/, require.resolve('./path/to/lib')]
  },
  {
    test: require.resolve('./path/to/lib'),
    loader: 'imports-loader?define=>false'
  }
]
```